# Cron job not running created by puppet

Tags: linux, cron, puppet

I want to add 1 cron job in to the machine that will run every 5 minutes, for that I am using this manifest:

```
class cron_job{

    file{"puppet_ls":
            path => "/puppet/pls.sh",
            ensure => present,
            content => "#!/bin/sh\necho \"Hello World\"\nls -ltr /etc/puppet > /puppet/dump.txt"
    }

    file { "my_ls.cron":
        path    => "/etc/cron.d/my_ls.cron",
        ensure  => present,
        owner   => "root",
        group   => "root",
        mode    => 0644,
        require => File["puppet_ls"],
        content => "*/1 * * * *  /puppet/pls.sh\n";
    }
}
```

So this manifest do 2 things,

1. It makes a file /puupet/pls.sh with the content specifie, that is actually running the command **ls-ltr /etc/puppet**
2. It makes an entry in the form of cron job for inside daily category and if you see the last line i.e  *** * * *  /puppet/pls.sh\n**, says that run after every 1 minute(for testing I kept one)

But I am not getting the file **dump.txt** inside **/puppet/**
Also if I runs, **sh /puppet/pls.sh**, it runs perfectly and generates the dump.

I am unable to understand where is the glitch..
:(

Please shed some light..

Thanks
Ankur

Answer (score 8):

You should use the [`cron` type](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#cron) that is built in to puppet.

```
file { '/puppet/pls.sh':
    content => "#!/bin/sh\necho \"Hello World\"\nls -ltr /etc/puppet > /puppet/dump.txt",
    mode    => 0755, 
}

cron { 'helloworld':   
   command => "/puppet/pls.sh",   
   user    => root,
   hour    => '*',   
   minute  => '*/5',
   require => File['/puppet/pls.sh']
}
```

```
........
```

Comment: The `cron` type built into puppet doesn't support system crontabs in /etc/cron.d: http://www.puppetcookbook.com/posts/managing-crond-entries.html

Answer (score 4):

Crontab files placed in /etc/cron.d, or other cron. directories under /etc cannot have periods in their name.

This is a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/debianutils/+bug/38022

Removing the period from your filename (my_ls.cron) should resolve the issue.